# How to omit key from an OCompositeKey?

Tags: orientdb

I created an edge index for properties (out: Link, in: Link, type: String)

I would like to query the index without specifying the `type` property via:

```
Iterable<Edge> edges = noTrx.getEdges("e." + label, new OCompositeKey(vertexA.getId(), vertexB.getId()));
```

Unfortunately no element could be found if i omit the type from the OCompositeKey.

Is there a way to query the index and omit the `type`? Or do I need to create a dedicated index which just contains out and in?

Full example source:

https://github.com/Jotschi/orientdb-playground/blob/e5bb027df171a04bc87d3b108ee58cc86499b7c3/src/test/java/de/jotschi/orientdb/EdgeIndexTest.java

Comment: Hi @Jotschi Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use hash index, so provided approach is correct. But if you will use tree based index and work with embedded database, you may use a composite key without type but in a bit tricky manner.  Instead of calling of getEdges function you should call

`index.iterateEntriesMajor(new OCompositeKey(root.getId(), foundElement.getId()))`

And then for each record in result call `graph.getEdge(record)`

I noticed that you use noTX graph implementation, I do not suggest to use the noTx implementation in production, it may lead to data inconsistency and broken graph state.

Answer (score 0):

Your class HAS_ITEM has two index

[image]

If you want to look also for the type you have to use the index e.has_item_type

```
Iterable<Edge> edges = noTrx.getEdges("e." + label +"_type", new OCompositeKey(root.getId(), foundElement.getId(),type));
```

else you could use index e.has_item

```
Iterable<Edge> edges = noTrx.getEdges("e." + label, new OCompositeKey(root.getId(), foundElement.getId()));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, so i am supposed to use a dedicated index. Got it. Thats also my current solution.